# Using NumPy argmax to count vs for loop

Tags: python, numpy

I currently use something like the similar bit of code to determine comparison

```
list_of_numbers = [29800.0, 29795.0, 29795.0, 29740.0, 29755.0, 29745.0]
high = 29980.0
lookback = 10
counter = 1

for number in list_of_numbers:
    if (high >= number) \
    and (counter < lookback):
        counter += 1
    else:
        break
```

The resulted `counter` magnitude will be `7`. However, it is very taxing on large data arrays. So, I have looked for a solution and came up with `np.argmax()`, but there seems to be an issue. For example the following:

```
list_of_numbers = [29800.0, 29795.0, 29795.0, 29740.0, 29755.0, 29745.0]
np_list = np.array(list_of_numbers)
high = 29980.0

print(np.argmax(np_list > high) + 1)
```

this will get output `1`, just like `argmax` is suppose to .. but I want it to get output `7`.  Is there another method to do this that will give me similar output for the if statement ?

Comment: Demonstrate how 7 is arrive in psudo code

Comment: @GoldenLion ```if (high >= number) and (counter < lookback):``` it will count until it arrives at it's first False statement and that is your output number

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get a boolean array for where `high >= number` using NumPy:

```
list_of_numbers = [29800.0, 29795.0, 29795.0, 29740.0, 29755.0, 29745.0]
high = 29980.0
lookback = 10

boolean_arr = np.less_equal(np.array(list_of_numbers), high)
```

Then finding where is the first **False** argument in that to satisfy `break` condition in your code. Furthermore, to consider countering, you can use `np.cumsum` on the *boolean array* and find the first argument that satisfying specified *lookback* magnitude. So, the result will be the smaller value between *break_arr* and *lookback_lim*:

```
break_arr = np.where(boolean_arr == False)[0][0] + 1
lookback_lim = np.where(np.cumsum(boolean_arr) == lookback)[0][0] + 1
result = min(break_arr, lookback_lim)
```

If your `list_of_numbers` have not any bigger value than your specified *high* limit for ***break_arr*** **or** the specified *lookback* exceeds values in `np.cumsum(boolean_arr)` for ***lookback_lim***, the aforementioned code will get stuck with an error like the following, relating to `np.where`:

> IndexError: index 0 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0

Which can be handled by `try-except` or `if` statements e.g.:

```
try:
    break_arr = np.where(boolean_arr == False)[0][0] + 1
except:
    break_arr = len(boolean_arr) + 1

try:
    lookback_lim = np.where(np.cumsum(boolean_arr) == lookback)[0][0] + 1
except:
    lookback_lim = len(boolean_arr) + 1
```

Answer (score 1):

You have you less than sign backwards, no? The following should work as the for-loop:

```
print(np.min([np.sum(np.array(list_of_numbers) < high) + 1, lookback]))
```

Answer (score 0):

A look back can be accomplished using shift.  A cumcount can be used to get a running total.  A query can be used as a filter